# How to separate the elements from one set into two other sets based on a condition?

Tags: python, set

I have a set containing names that begin with either A or with B. I want to separate the names into two sets, one containing names beginning with A and another beginning with B. Can somebody tell me the ways of solving this?

Here is my code

```
a = set()
b = set()
names = {'anand', 'bianca', 'benjamin', 'ayesha', 'brian', 'adarsh'}
print(names)

for ele in names:
      if ele == "a":
           a.add(ele)
      else:
           b.add(ele)

print("Set a contains : ", a)
print("Set b contains : ", b)
```

Comment: That _is_ how, but your condition is wrong - `ele == "a"` clearly does **not** meet the requirement _"begins with either A or with B"_.

Comment: I have tried this as well but it is giving an error - SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if ele is "a":

Comment: That's also clearly not the right condition, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/3001761. This isn't really a programming problem, you need to think about what "beginning with" actually means - "a" begins with a, sure, but so do many other strings.

Comment: 1) Are you just asking "Why is my code not working", or also "Is there a more elegant way to do this"?, 2) Can words start with other letters than `a` or `b` as well?

Comment: Now I want that "Is there a more elegant way to do this"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are just checking if `ele == a` while you should be checking if `ele` startswith `a` as below:

```
a = set()
b = set()
names = {'anand', 'bianca', 'benjamin', 'ayesha', 'brian', 'adarsh'}
print(names)

for ele in names:
      if ele.startswith("a"):
           a.add(ele)
      elif ele.startswith("b"):
           b.add(ele)

print("Set a contains : ", a)
print("Set b contains : ", b)
```

Output:

```
{'anand', 'bianca', 'benjamin', 'brian', 'adarsh', 'ayesha'}
Set a contains :  {'anand', 'adarsh', 'ayesha'}
Set b contains :  {'brian', 'benjamin', 'bianca'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming word start either with a or b:

```
names = {'anand', 'bianca', 'benjamin', 'ayesha', 'brian', 'adarsh'}
a = set(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('a'), names))
b = names.difference(a)
```

If there are other possibilities:

```
names = {'anand', 'bianca', 'benjamin', 'ayesha', 'brian', 'adarsh'}
a = set(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('a'), names))
b = set(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('b'), names))
```

output:

```
>>> a
{'adarsh', 'anand', 'ayesha'}
>>> b
{'benjamin', 'bianca', 'brian'}
```

*NB. this requires the elements of the set to be strings, else you need to check the type first*

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternative using `itertools.groupby`. The output is a dictionary, not separate variables:

```
from itertools import groupby
{k:set(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(names), lambda x: x[:1])}
```

output:

```
{'a': {'adarsh', 'anand', 'ayesha'}, 'b': {'benjamin', 'bianca', 'brian'}}
```

*NB. I am not sure if the `sorted` step is necessary*

Comment: Neat, but not sure if this always works without `sorted`ing the set first. Iteration order of elements in the set seems to be by hash code, which just works out in this case, but might not for other elements (and definitely not for other conditions). Alternatively: `for x in names: res[x[0]].add(x)` (`res` being `dict` or `defaultdict`)

Comment: Well, I am unable to understand this as I haven't reached lambda yet. Could you please explain the entire thing ? @mozway

Comment: `lambda x: x[:1]` takes the first (if any) character of the strings and `itertools.groupby` will use it to make groups. @tobias_k I'll look into it, but I'm pretty sure this is correct

Comment: In fact, it does not even work for this condition. On my system, the iteration order seems to be different, `list(names)` being `['benjamin', 'anand', 'adarsh', 'ayesha', 'bianca', 'brian']`, thus the first group is just `{benjamin}`, which is later silently overwritten with `{bianca, brian}`. (not my downvote, as I said, the basic idea is neat)

Comment: @tobias_k ok, thanks for the feedback, I guess it might be dependent on the python version, I updated the answer. However the initial input is a set not a list (for which sorted is for sure required)